# Factoring positive rational numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't understand how he goes from this:

$$2n(a+b)+a-b=1\,\,\,; \forall n\in \mathbb{N^*}, \,\,\, \mathbb{N^*}=\{1,2,3,...\}$$,

To this:

$$\begin{cases}
a+b=0 \\ 
a-b=1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I understand that this may have originated during an investigation into rational numbers, but nothing about this narrow question seems to involve rational numbers specifically. (This comment is in reference to the title of the question.)

Comment: Who?
                                              






${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Do you mean for all $n\in\mathbb N^*$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, thank you

Answer (score 3):

The statement is supposed to be true for all $n$. So writing it for $n=1$ and $n=2$ will give a system that can be reduced to this system.

$$\begin{align}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
2(a+b) + a-b &{}=1\\
4(a+b) + a-b &{}=1
\end{aligned}\right.\\
\left\{\begin{aligned}
2a+2b + a-b &{}=1\\
4a+4b + a-b &{}=1
\end{aligned}\right.\\
\left\{\begin{aligned}
3a+b &{}=1\\
5a+3b &{}=1
\end{aligned}\right.\\
\end{align}$$

Now twice the first equation minus the second yields $a-b=1$. And the second equation minus the first, divided by $2$, yields $a+b=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If an identity of polynomials, we have:
$$
2n(a + b) + a - b = 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 2n(a + b) + a - b = 0n + 1 \quad \Rightarrow
a + b = 0 \ \text{and} \ a - b = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Apply the Lemma below to $\ f(n)\, =\, 2(a\!+\!b)\, n + a\!-\!b\!-\!1.$

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\,f(n) = c_1 n + c_0\,$ then $\,f(0)=0=f(1)\,\Rightarrow\,c_0 = 0 = c_1 $ (i.e. $\,f = 0)$

**Proof** $\ \ 0 = f(0) = c_0,\ $ and  $\ 0 = f(1) = c_1\! + 0$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally if a polynomial $\,f\,$ over a domain/field has more roots than its degree, then $\,f\,$ is the zero polynomial $\,f = 0\,$ (i.e. all the coefficients of $\,f\,$ are $\,0).$